# Copying arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to copy an array in C#.
The definition of the first array is :
byte [][] a which contains 8 arrays each of size 8192 bytes.
The destination array is a 1d array of size 8192*8

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(a,0,b,0,8192*8)
```

where b is the destination array. However I keep getting Object must be an array of primitives. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you don't have a single array of value, you have an array of references to arrays of values.

The `byte[][]` type is not the same as the `byte[,]` type. The first is an array of arrays (aka jagged array) while the second is a two dimensional array.

You would need to copy each array by itself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
  Buffer.BlockCopy(a[i], 0, b, 8192 * i, 8192);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your first input array is not an array of primitives. It is an array of `byte[]` arrays.

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(a(array of byte[]) , 0, b (array of byte),0,8192*8)
```

Fix:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(a.SelectMany().ToArray(), 0, b, 0, 8192*8)
```

But to be honest I think you have the same result with:

```
var b = a.SelectMany().ToArray();
```